# How to delete table from mysql when uninstall extension frommagento 2.2.6?

Tags: database, extensions, magento2.2.6, uninstall-module, database-schema

I have created an extension with the schema. It is installed correctly and tables are created correctly in the database.

But, now I want to uninstall that extension.

But with uninstall, I also want to delete the tables which were created during the installation of the same extension.

is there any way to do this?

Comment: Login to your database , 1. run this query to show the table you want to delete is there **show tables;** ,  2. run **drop table `table_name`** , 3 run query **Delete from setup_module where module=`Namespace_Module`** , 4 Flush magento cache. 5 **php bin/magento cache:flush,
php bin/magento setup:upgrade,
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Answer (score 2):

For uninstalling the extension, you have to create a Setup/Uninstall.php file.

in that file for uninstall function, add following lines to drop your module table.

```
public function uninstall(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if ($setup->tableExists('module_table_name')) {
            $setup->getConnection()->dropTable('module_table_name');
        }
    }
```